# How to retry angular post request after delay based on response code

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs

I am working with an API that returns a HTTP "202 Accepted" response and begins processing a long running request.

I then need to post the same request after a delay until I receive a HTTP "200 OK" response at which point I can query the result from the response body.

I have reviewed the documentation and found several examples of retrying on error, however I cannot find how to retry after a delay on success.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpErrorResponse, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/throw';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/do';

@Injectable()
export class WebService {

  private _serviceUrl = 'https://webservice.com/api/long_request';

  constructor(private _http: HttpClient) { }

  getData() {

    let body = JSON.stringify({
      "time_properties":
      {
        "start_date": "2017-08-10",
        "end_date": "2017-08-14"        
      }
    });

    return this._http.post(this._serviceUrl, body)
      .do(data => console.log('All: ' + JSON.stringify(data)))
      .catch(this.handleError);
  }

  private handleError(err: HttpErrorResponse) {
    console.error(err.message);
    return Observable.throw(err.message);
  }
}
```

Comment: You can use `repeatWhen()` http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-repeatWhen

Comment: You can use `retryWhen()`: http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-retryWhen

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned use retry when like this. This will retry 3 times when you have 500 error

```
.retryWhen((errors) => {
            return errors.scan((errorCount, err) => {
                if (this.isNoUserError(err, this.unwrapHttpError(err))) {
                    if(errorCount >= 3) {
                        // return Observable.throw();
                        throw err;
                    }
                    return errorCount++;
                } else {
                    throw err;
                }
            }, 0);
        })

private isNoUserError(error, unwrapError) {
        return error.status === 500 && !!unwrapError && unwrapError.errorKey === "NO_USER";
    }


private unwrapHttpError(error: any): any {
        try {
            return (error.json());
        } catch (jsonError) {
            return ({
                code: -1,
                message: "An unexpected error occurred."
            });
        }
    }
```

for success just start again

```
loadSomething() {
   this.http.load().then(() => {
    if (code=== 202) {
     this.loadSomehitng();
     }
   })
 }
```

Comment: retryWhen only works with error status, I need to retry on HTTP 202.

Comment: @Simon just start then again you function updated the answer